# jQuery Mobile header buttons jump to top on iPhone Safari

Tags: header, scroll, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile to build a website and I have a 'fixed' header and footer, so we can show/hide the header and footer when the page is scrolled. The problem is that when we try to click a header button on the iPhone, the page scroll to the top, because the button is so close to the top of the viewport.

Is there any way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an iOS feature which enables you to jump back to the top of a site if you have scrolled all the way to the bottom of a page. Unfortunately you can't disable iOS functionality from within your website.

Comment: 187 It is unfortunate. Thanks :)